# Counting similar observations and dividing counts by given population

Tags: stata

[Snippet of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M9xFg.png)

I want a way in Stata to  count observations by `GeoIDtract` and then divide the count by the total population. For example, the tract 36005000100 has 5 observations and total population 7411. So I would want 5/7411 which would give me  0.00067 and then have that answer be put into a new variable `PropCrimeRate` for those 5 observations.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is a smoother way, but this works for me:

```
bys GeoIDtract: gen PropCrimeRate = _N/TotalPop
```

Comment: This is fine. As the ratios may be very small, holding them as a `double` may be a good idea.